# Mongoose async login issues

Tags: node.js, mongoose, async.js

having a real bear of a time with how to structure DB calls so that they're forced to load before the rest of functions.  This is a simple thing.  Need to find a user in a DB before I act on him.

So I'm trying parallel async.js with Mongoose calls right now.  I've tried 85 different ways to do this to be honest.

Here's the code:

```
async.parallel ([

   function(callback) {

       mongoose.connect(ConnString, function(error) {

       console.log("connection ok...")

       callback();

    });
  },

function(callback) {

    console.log("second function");

    callback();

}], 

function(error){

    console.log("in the error callback");

});
```

I will always get the same results.

```
second function
out of async... continuing
connection ok...
in the error callback
```

This is the simplest breakdown I can provide to help.  I've spent 6 hours on this issue, your help is appreciated!

Comment: FWIW: `async.parallel` runs your functions, well, parallel to each other. I think you meant to use `async.series`, where the next step is run only when the previous has finished.

Answer (score 0):

if what you're trying to do is make sure that you're db-connection is ready before you issue statements then don't bother. mongoose queues your requests until it's ready.

also, make sure you understand the implications of using the default connection (mongoose.connect) instead of a separate one (mongoose.createConnection).

the [main github page of mongoose](https://github.com/learnboost/mongoose) contains some interesting reading.

also, loose the async.parallel block... it's unnecessary. just write the code as is.

================================= EDIT ===============================

see if something like the following helps:

```
/* dependencies */
 var mongoose = require('mongoose');

/* schema definition */
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    phone: { type: String, required: true }
    // other user details here...
});

/* model definition */
var User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

/* static methods */
UserSchema.statics.isAuthorized = function (phone, cb) {
    User.find({ phone : { $in : [phone] } }).exec(function(err, data) {
        // logic & callback here...
    });
}; // eo isAuthorized(..)

// export the user.
module.exports = User;
```

You can now execute User.isAuthorozed(...)

Comment: My problem initially was that the DB queries weren't always ready.  I had setup a model that would export an authentication object... this object contained the query to find the user and a property indicating that he was valid.  When I referenced that from another model like: if (LoggedIn) {} it would always come back false since the queries weren't done executing?

Comment: This was the larger first flow:

in app.js
`
    logic = require('./models/logic.js');
    var Authorize = authenticate(req.param('From'));
    if (LoggedIn) {// logic here}
`
in logic.js
`
    module.exports.Authorize = Authorize;
    function Authorize(phone) {
 this.IsAuthorized = false;
    mongoose.connect(ConnString, function (error) {
  var query = User.find({})
  .where('Phone').in([phone])

  query.exec(function (err, result) {
           if (result.length != 0) {
         {
            this.IsAuthorized=true;
         }
         mongoose.connection.close();

Comment: i think the problem is with 'this'. try: var that = this; that.isAuthorized = false; ..... later -> that.isAuthorized = true; looks like a context issue.

Comment: unfortunately... no.  Perhaps the issue is module.exports.Authorize = Authorize;  Maybe exporting a function would be better...?